# MySQL Open Files Limit

Tags: mysql

I am tuning up my MySQL configurations, particularly on open_files_limit. I have set values in etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*       soft    nofile  100000
*       hard    nofile  200000
```

then in my.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 65535

[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 65535
```

After applying the changes I restarted my Apache2 and MySQL Services, I logged-in into MySQL and fetched the open_files_limit, the result is 100000. It is supposed to be 65535. Can anyone help me configure other values in MySQL in order to get the correct result? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase the value at /proc/sys/fs/file-max accordingly before increasing the open_files_limit variable in my.cnf

Hope this link helps you out .

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=872498

Comment: I had already set sysctl fs.file-max to

 fs.file-max = 1644849

is this enough? tried to restart services but still the same